# Adding alias properties (AliasProperty members)

Tags: powershell, properties, alias

I just wonder why this works:

```
$s = "hi there"
$s = Add-Member -InputObject $s -MemberType AliasProperty -Name Length2 -Value Length -PassThru
$s | gm -MemberType AliasProperty #the property is there
$s.Length2 #8
```

means: the aliasproperty Length2 is there, but this doesn't work:

```
$s = dir
$s = Add-Member -InputObject $s -MemberType AliasProperty -Name Length2 -Value Length -PassThru
$s | gm -MemberType AliasProperty #the property is not there
```

means: there is no aliasproperty Length2, but suprisingly enough:

```
$s.Length2 #458
```

works just fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `$s = dir`

Given that `dir` is a built-in alias for [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), this *typically* results in an *array* being stored in `$s`, i.e. whenever *two or more* child items (files or subdirectories) are present.<sup>[1]</sup>

> `$s = Add-Member -InputObject $s ...`

Due to use of [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member)'s  `-InputObject` parameter, you're adding the alias property (as an [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) member) to the *array itself*.

> `$s | gm -MemberType AliasProperty`

By contrast, due to using *the pipeline* here, which *enumerates* arrays, it is the *elements* of the array stored in `$s` that are being sent to [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) (whose built-in alias is `gm`) - and these do *not* have your alias property.

> `$s.Length2 #458`

Here you're accessing the alias property directly on the array, which therefore works.

---

As for **your *first* attempt** (which worked as expected):

> ```bash
> $s = "hi there"
> ```
>
> ```bash
> $s = Add-Member -InputObject $s -MemberType AliasProperty -Name Length2 -Value Length -PassThru
> ```

- Here `$s` is a *scalar* (single object), namely a `[string]` instance, and you're attaching the alias property directly to it.

  - As an aside: See the next section for why avoiding custom members to `[string]` instances is best avoided.
- Sending a scalar through the pipeline (`$s | gm -MemberType AliasProperty`) sends it as-is, so `Get-Member` (`gm`) was able to find its `.Length2` alias property.

---

###### Optional reading: Why attaching [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) members to *instances* of *`[string]`* and *.NET value types* is best avoided:

Note:

- The following recommendation applies to ETS members of any type that `Add-Member` is capable of adding to *instances* of .NET types, notably also to the more common `NoteProperty` members.
- See the next section for possible *bypassing* the problem via *type-level* ETS members.

***Avoid* attaching ETS *instance* members**:

- to **`[string]` instances**, because they require an *invisible `[psobject]` wrapper* that is *easily lost*, such as during string operations and strongly-typed parameter binding, resulting in loss of the ETS members; e.g.:

  ```bash
  $s = "hi there"

  # Add a .Length2 alias property that refers to .Length
  $s = Add-Member -InputObject $s -MemberType AliasProperty -Name Length2 -Value Length -PassThru -Force

  # OK: access the property directly on the decorated instance.
  $s.Length2 # -> 8, same as $s.Length

  # LOSS OF THE PROPERTY due to string operation.
  $s = $s -replace '$', '!'
  $s.Length2 # !! Property was LOST in the -replace operation.

  # LOSS OF THE PROPERTY during strongly typed parameter binding
  $s = Add-Member -InputObject $s -MemberType AliasProperty -Name Length2 -Value Length -PassThru -Force
  & { param([string] $str) $str.Length2 } $s
  ```
- to **instances of [*.NET value types*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)** (e.g, `[int]` (`System.Int32`); call `.IsValueType` on a type to check) for similar reasons: they too can be lost during strongly-typed parameter binding *and*, conversely - because PowerShell internally caches `[int]` instances from `0` to `100`, inclusively - can make the ETS member surface unexpectedly when these numbers are used *as literals*.

  ```bash
  $n = 42

  # Add a .Foo instance property of type NoteProperty with value 'Bar'
  $n = Add-Member -InputObject $n -MemberType NoteProperty -Name  Foo -Value Bar -PassThru

  # OK: access the property directly on the decorated instance.
  $n.Foo # -> 'Bar'

  # LOSS OF THE PROPERTY during strongly typed parameter binding
  & { param([int] $num) $num.Foo } $n

  # UNEXPECTED SURFACING OF THE PROPERTY in *integer literals*,
  # because the value is between 0 and 100.
  [int] $nCopy = 42
  $nCopy.Foo # !! -> 'Bar'
  ```

Note:

- It is the necessity of an invisible `[psobject]` wrapper that requires the use of `-PassThru` in the `Add-Member` calls above, along with *re-assigning the result to the original variable* (`$s = Add-Member -PassThru -InputObject $s ...`)
- By contrast, this invocation form is *not* necessary for decorating instance of [.NET *reference types*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) *other than `[string]`*, and such instances aren't affected by the problems above.

---

###### Optional reading: *Instance*-level vs. *type*-level ETS members:

**ETS members can also be defined at the *type* level** (rather than at the *instance* level, i.e. *for a particular object only*), namely via [`Update-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata), which is ***often preferable***, though not always called for / possible.

- In the case of an `AliasProperty` member, a *type-level* definition is the better choice, given that *all instances* of the given type then automatically have this property:

  ```bash
  # Add an alias property 'Length2' to the [string] (System.String) *type*
  Update-TypeData -TypeName System.String -MemberType AliasProperty -MemberName Length2 -Value Length

  # Now every string instance has this property.
  'foo'.Length2 # -> 3
  ```
- In the case of an *instance-specific* `NoteProperty` member value, a *type-level* definition as an alternative is only an option if the value can be *derived* from the instance's type-native properties, via a `ScriptProperty` member, i.e., a property whose value is *dynamically calculated*, via a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) that can act on the instance at hand via the [automatic `$this` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#this); e.g.:

  ```bash
  # Add a `.MaxIndex` script property that is the string's
  # length - 1, i.e. the index of the last char. in the string.
  Update-TypeData -TypeName System.String -MemberType ScriptProperty -MemberName MaxIndex -Value { $this.Length - 1 }

  # Now every string instance has this - dynamically calculated - property.
  'foo'.MaxIndex # -> 2
  'food'.MaxIndex # -> 3
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Specifically, it is an `[object[]]` array containing [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and/or [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instances.</sup>