# Adding a member on PSobject after receiving it from Invoke Rest-Method results in the Object being $null

Tags: powershell, rest, csv, psobject

I'm using the Invoke-RestMethod to gather information on IP-Addresses from a list automatically. While that itself works like a breeze, I am required to add a timestamp for each time the computer makes a query to the API endpoint, which is where it is resulting in problems when exporting the whole thing into a CSV file:

I am very new to PowerShell since today (except for simply running some pre-written scripts when working in IT Help Desk) but the following problem is current:

When appending the data to the CSV file in the output path, no problems occur - but of course the requirement of the timestamp as a column is missing.

However, when I try to use the Add-Member method to add the new hashvalue to the PSobject resulting from the query (or when I simply import the csv, add the column with the timestamp and export it back to the output file) the whole thing results in $null.

Why does this happen? Is there any way I can possibly add those timestamps into the CSV after each iteration properly?

Code snippet:

```
try { 
        $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
        Invoke-RestMethod @Params 
        | Select-Object ip, country_code, as, is_proxy
        | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "query_date_and_time" -Value $timestamp
        | Export-Csv $OutputPath -Append
        
        # $arr += $Result

        Write-Host "$Result"
        
    } catch { 
        Throw $_.Exception
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) cmdlet is somewhat unusual in that it modifies its input object *in place*, instead of *outputting* a modified object, and by default produces *no output* - that's why `Export-Csv` received no input.

However, you can use the `-PassThru` switch to request that the modified object be output as well.

Therefore (pipeline reformatted to be Windows PowerShell-compatible):

```bash
Invoke-RestMethod @Params | 
  Select-Object ip, country_code, as, is_proxy |
  Add-Member -PassThru -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'query_date_and_time' -Value $timestamp |
  Export-Csv $OutputPath -Append
```

As an aside:

- `-Append` will append to a preexisting output file on every run. If, instead, the intent is to write the file (anew) in full on every run, omit `-Append`.
- For technical reasons, `[string]` instances and instance of .NET *value types* can *not* be modified in-place, and in this case you need to combine `-PassThru` with assigning the result back to the input variable (e.g., `$var = 101; $var = $var | Add-Member -PassThru Foo Bar`); however decorating instances of these types is *best avoided*, for the reasons explained in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77167480/45375).

Comment: This solved it, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @stanleysearles; my pleasure.